# How to write a navigation bar in one place and use it across all pages with just html/css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sure I remember doing this once but can't remember how.

What I'm trying to do is write a navbar in html in one place and have every page take the html code from the file and add it to the page when the page loads. PHP doesn't work (I suspect I need a server for PHP to work which I don't even intend to use)

Something like:

Navbar file:

```
<div>
    other code...
</div>
```

Main webpage file:

```
<html>
    <header>
    </header>

    <body>
    </body>

    <div>
        put navbar file code here...
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: One word. _AJAX_! You could also use frames but they are discouraged.

Comment: Every basic server out there has support for PHP why would you not use it? It's as simple as `require('menu.php')`, and done!

Comment: Because I'm not using a server...

Comment: Your computer _is_ the server then, all you need is to install XAMPP or with PHP installed all you need for a quick server is `php -S localhost:1234`.

Comment: It doesn't sound like he wants or NEEDS to use PHP. Why the force.

Comment: But then don't I have to set up a server to run?

Comment: How about using an iframe?

Comment: @Althaen: If you're testing locally, with the built-in PHP server you don't need Apache, so it's really that quick to set up. All you need is PHP installed. What is this website for anyway? A bit more info would help to know your needs because you may want to use AJAX as well...

Comment: It's really just me messing around with html and js for the hell of it. I wasn't planning on doing server stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="file_with_only_div_content.html" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I guess if it's just for local crap, this will work. @Althaen Why not set up a local server again? But if it's for navigation he'll have to have a bunch of javascript to change the parent window and not the iframe window.

Comment: `<base target="_parent" />` can just go in the iframe file

Comment: Ah... shows you how much I use iFrames. Not ideal generally, but I guess in his case, it is.

Comment: iframe has become obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

You mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes server side includes?

```
<!--#include virtual="../quote.txt" -->
```

Are these even supported anymore?

**In order for a web server to recognize an SSI-enabled HTML file and therefore carry out these instructions, either the filename should end with a special extension, by default .shtml, .stm, .shtm, or, if the server is configured to allow this, set the execution bit of the file.**

Comment: I tried doing that and nothing happened, it's really annoying me now.

Comment: I'm not actually putting this on a server.

Comment: The computer with the content is the server. So unless you are making your webpage on a notepad with a pen, technically you are. Though I am not sure if SSI will work.

Comment: Quick google search tells me this wont work when not on an actual server. It sounds like you need to either set up a server or use PHP. OR I guess you could use javascript since this sounds like something for personal use.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by only html/css/js and not php or client-to-server/server-to-client based code.

Comment: Well technically server side includes are just HTML, which is why i suggested it. You didn't say no client-to-server. I still think you can set up your computer running the site to act as a server, but I don't know how to do that. Just use AJAX.

Comment: AJAX will throw XHR issues in browsers like Chrome when running locally